# intelliJ Find Usages

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

In Netbeans the Find Usages feature only finds usages in java class..it doesnt find usages in JSP code.

Does intelliJ find usages for a method in a JSP scriptlet as well?

Comment: guess this answers it...http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/jsp_editor.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it finds usages in any file under the directories that you've specified as "source directories".  It has problems with determining whether or not a matching word in dynamically typed files (example: Groovy) are actually references to your object.  Sometimes you get false positives in that situation and sometimes they don't appear in the results (kind of frustrating).  But other than that it works like a charm.